# configure nginx for PHP in subfolder

Tags: nginx, php, fastcgi

I wish to serve an old app that lives in a folder - the folder contains everything needed - index.html, various .js and a "server.php" backend. index.html works fine, but I get 404 for the calls to server.php.

My config:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name server.xxx;

    ssl on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/greenmapp.eu.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/greenmapp.eu.key;

    include /etc/nginx/conf/ssl.conf;

    include /etc/nginx/conf/rest.v2.conf;

    root /var/lib/treemapp/node/v3.3/;

    index index.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    }

    location @rewrites {
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
    }


    location /app {
        alias /var/www/v3.1.3/www/; #this works, 
    }

    location /app/server.php { # This doesn't work - I get 404
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The php config works in another config I have for a different hostname that points to the same physical folder.

What to do?

Comment: Check that the file `/var/lib/treemapp/node/v3.3/app/server.php` actually exists.

Comment: A-ha - server.php exists in /var/www/v3.1.3/www. Should I do an alias to it?

Comment: That seems like a good idea.

Comment: That fixed it - thank you :) I added `alias /var/www/v3.1.3/www/server.php;` at the start of the `location  /app/server.php {}` block